# Override methods not being called in Android

Tags: java, android, json, overriding

I have a class `VisitMapper.java` which is extending from `JSONObject` class. In the `VisitMapper.java` class I am overriding two methods of `JSONObject` class `getString()` and `getJSONObject()`. Here is my code:

**VisitMapper.java**

```
 public final class VisitMapper extends JSONObject{

        private static final String DISPLAY_KEY = "display";

        private VisitMapper() {
        }

        public static Visit map(JSONObject jsonObject) throws JSONException {
            Visit visit = new Visit();
            visit.setUuid(jsonObject.getString("uuid"));
            visit.setVisitPlace(jsonObject.getJSONObject("location").getString(DISPLAY_KEY));
            visit.setVisitType(jsonObject.getJSONObject("visitType").getString(DISPLAY_KEY));
            visit.setStartDate(DateUtils.convertTime(jsonObject.getString("startDatetime")));
            visit.setStopDate(DateUtils.convertTime(jsonObject.getString("stopDatetime")));

            return visit;
        }

        @Override
        public String getString(String name) throws JSONException {
            String tempName = "";
            System.out.println("getString() is being called: "+name);
            if (this.has(name) && !this.isNull(name)){

                tempName = super.getString(name);
            }
            return tempName;
        }

        @Override
        public JSONObject getJSONObject(String name) throws JSONException {
            JSONObject tempObject = null;
            System.out.println("getJSONOBJECT() is being called");
            if (this.has(name) && !this.isNull(name)){

                tempObject = super.getJSONObject(name);
            }
            if (tempObject==null){

            }
            return tempObject;
        }
    }
```

I checked my logcat the `System.out.println()` calls are not printed. I went through some questions of this type they mentioned that the methods should not be static or local to the package, they should not be private. you must inherit the parent class etc. With these two methods there is no problem of this sort. I am inheriting my java class from `JSONObject.java`. I am not able to understand where I am wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's calling `map`? Is it actually passing in a `VisitMapper` object? If not, then no, your overrides won't be called...

Comment: I am calling map like this: `Visit visit = VisitMapper.map(visitResultJSON.getJSONObject(i));` it's in a loop with incrementing variable `i`. Actually, I am fetching response from server and parsing JSON like this. It is generating JSON exception because I am not checking for values in returned JSON. So I tried overriding these two methods.

Comment: So what is `visitResultJSON`? Basically, if nothing is actually creating a `VisitMapper`, that would certainly explain it...

Comment: Inside visitResultJSON.getJSONObject(i) : How you are creating JSONObject's instance ?

Comment: Yes, I am not creating any instance of VisitMapper class, I am directly calling the method because it's static. So I have to create an instance and then call the method? Or remove the `static` keyword. Can you tell me why overriding does not works like this?

Comment: There is no issue in that you can call static method map(). But the object you are passing to map() method should be instantiated as ViewMapper.

Comment: It sounds like you need to revisit the basics of polymorphism, basically: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html

Comment: @JonSkeet My bad, I should have read the docs carefully. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Json object into `map(JsonObject jsonObject)` will only use the methods you override if the instance of JsonObject is VisitMapper (`JsonObject json = new VisitMapper()`).

If the instance of JsonObject is itself (`JsonObject json = new JsonObject()`), the methods `getString` and `getJsonObject` will came from JsonObject.class

To check the instance of an object, you can write :

```
if(jsonObject instanceof VisitMapper){
    //here you can access your override methods
} else if (jsonObject instanceof JsonObject) {
    //here you cannot access your override methods
}
```

**Update**

Add link provided by Jon Skeet about polymorphism: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It would be better if you update your answer with the link to the java docs provided by Jon Skeet in the comments. docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html